# Select record based on child column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to fetch data based on child table condition, but it's returning a wrong result.

If the child table date is less than today, then it updates `IsActive` to true, otherwise to false.

Parent table has 1 record and child table has 20 records

```
select * 
from parenttable 
where exist (select * 
             from childtable child, parenttable parent 
             where changedate < getdate() 
             and parent.id = child.id)
```

Subquery returns the correct answer. But I think issue is with exist

Comment: The problem you have that your outer parenttable is not linked to the exists query in any way, so if the inner query finds even one row, the outer query will not return anything

Comment: thanks James for reply..can u please le me know how can i use this

Comment: Please share the table structure to work

Comment: Sorry yashveer singh i can't share proper table structure but may be it's help you  Parent table have 3 column name,id,IsActive and child table column are parenttableid, orderno, cdate,

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subquery returns the correct data, then get rid of the outer portion of the query, and just return data from the subquery:

```
select parent.* 
from childtable child
INNER JOIN parenttable parent 
    on parent.id=child.id
where changedate < getdate()
```

The exists check doesn't need to occur at all. If you want to ensure that only a single row is returned per parent, just add a DISTINCT clause:

```
select DISTINCT
    parent.* 
from childtable child
INNER JOIN parenttable parent 
    on parent.id=child.id
where changedate < getdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a `join` as such, the "child table" in the `exists`  clause (yes it is `exists` and  not `exist`) needs to be "linked" to the parent table like in

```
select * from parenttable p where exists
  (select * from childtable c 
   where c.pid=p.id and changedate < getdate())
```

assuming there is a column `pid` in child table that corresponds to the `id` column in the parent table.

Comment: thanks cars for reply..but i allready try this but it didn't work.Can i use anything else rather then exists

Comment: Maybe you can set up a small fiddle with sample data? Maybe here: http://rextester.com .